# Can netfilter act as a DHCP relay?

Tags: dhcp, container, nftables, tc, netfilter

I'm wondering whether instead of using a DHCP relay netfilter (be that `tc` or `nftables`) can be used to route DHCP broadcast packets to a Docker container attached to a bridge.

The reasoning for this is that I'd like to move away from having to use a `macvlan` DHCP container so it can appear as if one IP (i.e. the router IP) is handling all of the network operations. DHCP containers usually require `CAP_NET_ADMIN` (due to DHCP requiring promiscuous mode) and I understand that without a `macvlan` this would give control over the host's network stack (I also `userns-remap` my containers).

It would be great if it were possible to modify the DHCP packets and forward them on. A relay wouldn't work here as it would still require the same `macvlan` approach as the DHCP container already has.

Is this something that's possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would appear so, and I have an imperfect solution. Please note that the effectiveness of this solution may vary depending on network configuration.

The DHCP server is located within a Docker bridge network and is being run with `CAP_NET_BIND`, `CAP_NET_RAW`, and `CAP_NET_ADMIN`, giving it control over the network namespace in which it runs.

In order for the [`DHCPDISCOVER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Discovery) packets to reach the DHCP server, the following rule is used:

```
table netdev filterearly_lan {
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device eth0 priority -500; policy drop;
        
        ip saddr 0.0.0.0 ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp sport 68 udp dport 67 ip saddr set $LOCAL_NETWORK ip daddr set $DHCP meta pkttype set host accept;
    }
}
```

This avoids the trouble set out in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756233/nftables-forward-layer-2-broadcast-dhcp-without-ingress-chain) question and means the packets traverse netfilter normally, enabling sending to an `NFQUEUE` thus:

```
table inet filter {
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;

        udp sport 68 udp dport 67 queue num 0;
        udp sport 67 udp dport 68 queue num 0;
    }
}
```

`$LOCAL_NETWORK` can be any IP within the subnet but for some reason cannot be the IP of the local device. It appears to be possible to set it as the network address (e.g. 192.168.1.0). It does not appear that the destination MAC address needs to be changed.

To handle clients that request responses using broadcast the packet type must be changed to host in order to be routed and the destination IP can be retrieved from the [`DHCPOFFER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Offer) packet (`ingress` isn't used here to keep things interface agnostic):

```
table inet filter {
    chain raw {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -400; policy accept;

        ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp sport 67 udp dport 68 @nh,128,32 set @th,192,32 meta pkttype set host;
    }
}
```

When `DHCPOFFER` packets were sent as unicast I was having [problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756580/nftables-setting-destination-mac-still-sending-arp-requests) with ARP requests being sent out (at the `postrouting` stage) for the client before it had been given its IP. To bypass this issue:

```
table inet mangle {
    chain postrouting {
        type filter hook postrouting priority 50;

        udp sport 67 ether daddr set ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ip daddr set 255.255.255.255;
    }       
}
```

Once past the stage ARP requests are made, it is possible to restore the destination MAC and IP from the contents of the [`DHCPOFFER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Offer) and have them sent to the correct destination(s). The TTL should also be restored so as not to arouse suspicion upon packet analysis:

```
table netdev filterearly_lan {
    chain egress {
        type filter hook egress device eth0 priority 500; policy accept;

            #Restore the TTL that is changed during the routing process
            udp sport 67 ip ttl set 64 continue;                        
            #Client asked for broadcast
            udp sport 67 @th,256,48 0x800000000000 ip daddr set 255.255.255.255 ether daddr set ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;
            #Set the ether addr to the CHADDR. Only if unicast flag
            udp sport 67 @th,256,48 0x000000000000 @ll,0,48 set @th,400,48;
            #Set the ip daddr from the YIADDR. Only if unicast flag
            udp sport 67 @th,256,48 0x000000000000 @nh,128,32 set @th,304,32;
    }
}
```

The replies need to be [`SNAT`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)#Source_NAT)ed correctly as they come from a different network:

```
table inet nat {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;

        oifname "eth0" masquerade;
    }
}
```

Out of scope of this question and answer is the configuration of the DHCP server and any required modifications to the packet(s). Ideally the DHCP server would support providing IP addresses to a different network. If the server cannot spoof its IP then packet modification would be required to alter the `SIADDR` and DHCP [option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Options) 54 (server identifier).

With this configuration it's possible to use DHCP servers behind a Docker bridge, fufulling the requirements set out in the original question.

Comment: Very thorough explanation!

Comment: Thanks :) I've also just added handling broadcast `DHCPOFFER`s

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that sounds feasible: DHCP being a perfectly cromulent UDP/IP protocol, `nftables` should be able to just forward all ethernet frames for FF:…:FF with IP source address 0.0.0.0 and the 255.255.255.255 broadcast target to the network interface and IP address of your container.

But: your DHCP server software might not want that; it might require binding to the layer 2 (`AF_PACKET`, with socket type `SOCK_RAW`, protocol `ETHER_TYPE`, typically) socket (see `man 7 packet`) instead of a transport layer socket (i.e., UDP socket, `AF_INET`, `SOCK_DGRAM`). It depends, but I bet that is configurable with most DHCP servers.

Comment: IIRC DHCP packets have some fields that are filled by relays, and you also need to not only get the requests in the right place, but the replies too. I'm not sure how much those are a problem in this context, but they might be something that needs to be considered.

Comment: I've run into a problem: The DHCP server can't get the DHCPOFFER back to the client because the destination MAC is lost as the server sends the offer through the default gateway. This results in endless ARP requests for who has the given IP, but of course the client doesn't have the IP yet.

Comment: That sounds like you're doing routing between host and VM: not what I recommended you do.

Comment: I'm able to `fwd` the broadcasts to another NIC, however I'm trying to avoid using `fwd` along with having to specify interfaces because of what I'm doing in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756233/nftables-forward-layer-2-broadcast-dhcp-without-ingress-chain)