# nftables - Forward layer 2 broadcast (DHCP) without ingress chain?

Tags: dhcp, nftables, netfilter

I'm currently [looking into](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754420/can-netfilter-act-as-a-dhcp-relay) setting up DHCP servers behind a Docker bridge. My docker bridges are brought up with `docker compose`. I'm looking for a way to forward incoming `DHCPDISCOVER` requests to the bridged network. I have an IPS set up in `NFQUEUE` mode which I intend to use to inspect (and [alter](https://docs.suricata.io/en/suricata-7.0.0/rules/payload-keywords.html#replace)*) some DHCP packets. It does not appear possible to use `queue num` on `ingress` or `egress` chains.

I understand that it's possible to use `fwd` on `ingress` chains, however this presents two problems:

- Packets `fwd`ed are `NF_STOLEN` [meaning](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO.txt) that further traversal does not happen, preventing the packets from being sent to the IPS.
- `fwd` rules and `ingress` chains require a NIC to be named. Since Docker brings these interfaces up dynamically this doesn't seem like a clean solution and adds overhead having to add tables and chains later on.

To this end, I've tried the following:

```
table inet nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;

        ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff udp sport 68 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 dnat to 172.25.10.5;
    }
}
```

and

```
table netdev filterearly_lan {
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device enp1s0.10 priority -500; policy accept;
    
        ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff udp sport 68 ip daddr set 172.25.10.5;
    }
}
```

However nothing seems to appear in the output of `tcpdump -i br-a039f83f0bc5 port 67 and port 68 or arp -nne`.

Is it possible to perform this sort of fowarding without anything requiring a NIC to be named? Thanks

* To alter the DHCP server IP (option 54) field because nftables won't reach that far into the packet.