# nftables - Setting destination MAC still sending ARP requests

Tags: routing, dhcp, nftables, netfilter, arp

I'm [trying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754420/can-netfilter-act-as-a-dhcp-relay/) to run DHCP servers behind a private Docker bridge.

I'm at a point where I can reroute the `DHCPDISCOVER` broadcast packets to the DHCP server behind the Docker bridge and have the DHCP respond with a `DHCPOFFER`:

```
table netdev filterearly {
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device enp1s0.10 priority -500; policy accept;
            ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff udp sport 68 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 ether daddr set a0:ce:c8:ef:42:64 ip saddr set 192.168.1.0 ip daddr set 172.25.10.5 meta pkttype set host;
    }
}
```

```
root@debian:~# tcpdump -i br-a039f83f0bc5 port 67 and port 68 or arp -nne
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on br-a039f83f0bc5, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
08:47:48.520078 02:42:b6:0c:71:65 > 02:42:ac:19:0a:05, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 192.168.1.0.68 > 172.25.10.5.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 08:00:27:b7:6d:8e, length 300
08:47:51.528778 02:42:ac:19:0a:05 > 02:42:b6:0c:71:65, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 172.25.10.5.67 > 192.168.1.144.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
```

However this `DHCPOFFER` is not making it out of the interface due to the system keep sending ARP requests:

```
root@debian:~# tcpdump -i enp1s0.10 port 67 and port 68 or arp -nne
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp1s0.10, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
08:46:12.556651 08:00:27:b7:6d:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 08:00:27:b7:6d:8e, length 300
08:46:12.557763 f0:2f:74:2d:28:88 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.144 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
08:46:13.577352 f0:2f:74:2d:28:88 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.144 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
```

To combat this, I'm setting the destination MAC address from the `CHADDR` field in the [`DHCPOFFER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Offer):

```
table inet mangle {
    chain postrouting {
        type filter hook postrouting priority 50;
        udp sport 67 @ll,0,48 set @th,288,48;   
    }       
}
```

Despite this, ARP requests are still being sent.

From the `nft monitor trace` I can see towards the end of the traversal that the packets make it up to `inet nat postrouting`, which presumably is when the ARP lookups begin.

```
...
trace id 537265a7 inet filter forward packet: iif "br-a039f83f0bc5" oif "enp1s0.10" ether saddr 02:42:ac:19:0a:05 ether daddr 02:42:b6:0c:71:65 ip saddr 172.25.10.5 ip daddr 192.168.1.144 ip dscp cs6 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 63 ip id 53344 ip protocol udp ip length 328 udp sport 67 udp dport 68 udp length 308 @th,64,96 0x2010600fc731d6f00000000 
trace id 537265a7 inet filter forward rule meta nftrace set 1 (verdict continue)
trace id 537265a7 inet filter forward verdict continue 
trace id 537265a7 inet filter forward policy accept 
trace id 537265a7 inet mangle postrouting packet: iif "br-a039f83f0bc5" oif "enp1s0.10" ether saddr 02:42:ac:19:0a:05 ether daddr 08:00:27:b7:6d:8e ip saddr 172.25.10.5 ip daddr 192.168.1.144 ip dscp cs6 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 63 ip id 53344 ip protocol udp ip length 328 udp sport 67 udp dport 68 udp length 308 @th,64,96 0x2010600fc731d6f00000000 
trace id 537265a7 inet mangle postrouting rule udp sport 67 @ll,0,48 set @th,288,48 (verdict continue)
trace id 537265a7 inet mangle postrouting verdict continue 
trace id 537265a7 inet mangle postrouting policy accept 
trace id 537265a7 inet nat postrouting packet: iif "br-a039f83f0bc5" oif "enp1s0.10" ether saddr 02:42:ac:19:0a:05 ether daddr 08:00:27:b7:6d:8e ip saddr 172.25.10.5 ip daddr 192.168.1.144 ip dscp cs6 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 63 ip id 53344 ip protocol udp ip length 328 udp sport 67 udp dport 68 udp length 308 @th,64,96 0x2010600fc731d6f00000000 
trace id 537265a7 inet nat postrouting rule meta nftrace set 1 (verdict continue)
trace id 537265a7 inet nat postrouting rule iifname "br-a039f83f0bc5" oifname "enp1s0.10" masquerade (verdict accept)
```

**Is there a way to tell netfilter to not perform ARP and just send the packet out with the current header information?**

Thanks