# nftables set (verb) with concatenation

Tags: nftables, netfilter

**Note:** This is about using concatentation (`.`) from a `set` to use the `set` verb to modify parts of the packet (e.g. `ip daddr set 1.2.3.4`). I don't seem to be able to find the specific nomenclature from the [man page](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html).

Working from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757378/453584) answer I have the following extract from my `nftables` config:

```
define src_net      = 192.168.1.0
define docker_dhcp  = 172.25.10.5
define WAN_MAC      = [REDACTED]

table netdev filterearly_lan {
    set dhcp_setting {
        typeof vlan id . ip saddr . ip daddr
        flags interval
        elements = {
            5 . $src_net . $docker_dhcp,
        }       
    }
    
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device eth0 priority -500; policy drop;

        #DHCPDISCOVER
        ether type 0x8100 vlan id . ip saddr 0.0.0.0 ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp sport 68 udp dport 67 ether daddr set $WAN_MAC ip saddr set . ip daddr set @dhcp_setting meta pkttype set host ip length <= 590 accept;
    }
}
```

But it appears to not work when trying to `set` some fields:

```
# nft -f ./dhcp.rules
./dhcp.rules:323:167-167: Error: syntax error, unexpected .
                ether type 0x8100 vlan id . ip saddr 0.0.0.0 ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp sport 68 udp dport 67 ether daddr set $WAN_MAC ip saddr set . ip daddr set @dhcp_setting meta pkttype set host ip length <= 590 accept;
                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
```

This rule in intended to replace a repeated collection of rules:

```
ether type 0x8100 vlan id 5 ip saddr 0.0.0.0 ether daddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp sport 68 udp dport 67 ether daddr set $WAN_MAC ip saddr set $src_net ip daddr set $docker_dhcp meta pkttype set host ip length <= 590 accept;
...
```

Version information:

```
# nft -v
nftables v1.0.6 (Lester Gooch #5)
# uname -r
6.1.0-11-amd64
```

Is using concatentation in this way possible at all? Thanks

Comment: You would need a map rather than a set to use the set keyword: a set returns only a boolean (present/not present), but you want values to replace, so that's a map. BUT I don't think that today, except for NAT, you can use concatenation as result, only a single value. So in the end I'd say: "not implemented", but I could be wrong. That's not even counting the little details. Eg1: expecting that src_net because of its name will magically match the LAN without additional care: with interval. Eg2: what about the vlan value 5 in the set (that should be a map)?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much information about `map`s when used outside of `nat`. The syntax even when used with `nat` is confusing and to me doesn't seem very explanatory within the man page and wiki? It could well be that this isn't possible